# Exclude folders and files from static deployment

Tags: magento2

Is it possible to exclude files and folders from static deployment? In my case, I have a `node_modules` folder located in my theme folder. Right now, this folder is also copied to the `pub/static` folder.

The `node_modules` folder is located in the theme folder because I have a different Gulp configuration with different dependencies per theme. I'm not using the Grunt configuration Magento has provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to exclude the files from deployment, if they reside in your theme's `web` directory.
To avoid publishing them, move the files to the theme's root directory.